# Nginx unclear about non HTTP requests

Tags: http, nginx

Today my website server had to be restarted. It seems it faced an important number of requests that do not look like HTTP ones. While the density of requests reduced, I can still see some of them reaching my server.

Here is an example of the Nginx log:

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [08/Apr/2022:01:33:43 +0000] "8,z\xE6i\xF2\x22\xCBsF%*\x99\xD5\xF9s\x90\xB5\xA0,\x91\xDE\xE5\xCD6\x8F\
xF5\xD2x\xE4\xED\xB4\x19/\xC0\xF6N\xDFpv\xD7\xB9I\x9A\x06O,\xCE\xBF\xA1\xED\x82\x98\x18\xCF\x1B" 400 166 "-" "-"
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  - - [08/Apr/2022:01:33:43 +0000] "}\xE8\x8DW\xCC/\xB4\x17I\xE8o\x19\xCD\x8F\x9F\xBB\x88\xB3mM\xEB\x22R\x19
\x01\xBF\xD3\xA2\x8F\xEEA\xC4\xBD\xF2\xCB\x89x?\xD6\x8B\xC9\xA5f\x9B\x9FV\x19\xBE]\x1B\xC4O\xF4\xD6\xA4\xBD\xEF\x04\xFBl\
xAB\xEF\xA7\x0Bu\xEE\xBB\xFF\xE1/7\x1F\xF7" 400 166 "-" "-"
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  - - [08/Apr/2022:01:33:44 +0000] "U\xF0\xD8\xD1\x8D" 400 166 "-" "-"
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  - - [08/Apr/2022:01:33:45 +0000] "?\xDD\x0E\xE8\xBD\xDB\xF7\x00\x89\x18\xE0^(\xAF\x80\x08M\x12\xA5 \xF2\x0
C\x1D_\xB8\xA3\xAA\x84\x5C\x06*\x10\xB4U\xC0BAH\x94\xA0\xC6\x13A\xD9\xA1T\xF4\xCFZ\xF9\xAB\x06k\x15\x03\xCC+VHg\xFD\xCF\x
AF\xA4\x1Fk`R\x8Ff\xF7\xFC\xB3\xD2\xE7\x0F/\x15y\xA4\xEB\xEEg\xAD\xAF\xFEw\xDF\x84\x96\xB5\x93\x81r|\x11}-\xC389\x88\x0C\
xDF\xA3\xAA\xBE\x81.\x13T\x09\xC6\x8D\xCF<\xDF\xE7h\xE0\x17\xBD\x9C\xEA\x17\xF2s\xF1\xB8\x89\xC9#\xA6\xC72\x94?\xB7kD\xBB
\xB2\xA7 \x8E\xE7" 400 166 "-" "-"
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  - - [08/Apr/2022:01:33:45 +0000] "2\x93g\x85\xB6\xE2\x89{\xB2\x15\x0Eg}\xC5\xBC&\x9C(l" 400 166 "-" "-"
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  - - [08/Apr/2022:01:33:46 +0000] "KYK\xB2" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

The IP is the one of a web hosting platform. It is not the only one I was able to identify.
My understanding is that Nginx returns 400 responses which is the expected behaviour.

Is there a way to understand better these requests reaching my server?

Can I prevent them by using a service like Cloudflare?

Is this a security issue for my website?